# 'ORA-06413: Connection not open' only in Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm pretty new in rails. I've a problem with Oracle.
I always get **ORA-06413: Connection not open** error from oracle when I run the rails server

I'm using this configuration

```
ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3' 
gem 'pg', '= 0.18.1'
gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.2.4'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter','~> 5.2.3'
...
```

My database.yml is

```
oracle_db:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: //192.168.0.2:1521/PRODUCTION
  username: username
  password: password

development:
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: username
  password: password
  host: 192.168.0.3
  database: my_db
```

I'm wrote this class to retrieve last person code insered in oracle DB

```
class Oracle < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :oracle_db
  scope :open, -> { where(FIELD: 'FC').order(created_at: :desc) }
  
  def self.GetLastPersonCode
    myquery =  "SELECT CODE FROM table WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CODE DESC"
    result = self.connection.select_one(myquery)
    if result["code"].nil?
      codice = "NEW200000"
    else
      record = result["code"].to_s.strip
      code = "NEW"+(record[3..].to_i+1).to_s
    end
    return code
  end
end
```

When I insert a new person in my PG database I want to find last code in oracle_db and create a new one. I'm using this code

```
@person = Person.new(person_params_post)
@person.code = Oracle.GetLastPersonCode
@person.save
```

Now, all works fine But when I try to recover the code I get the error 'ORA-06413: Connection not open'.
The thing that I don't explain is that... if from rails console I launch the Oracle.GetLastPersonCode I correctly recover the person code. I'm using visual studio code on Debian Buster.

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4.1)
2.6.3 :001 > Oracle.GetLastPersonCode
   (1163.3ms)  SELECT ....WHERE ROWNUM = 1
 => "CFC192957"
```

What change between server and console environment?